# Vue router not matching route with more than one slash

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

basically my issue is that I want to pass a router prop called `name` into an article route, so something like `/article/:name`. When I direct to that route internally, like with `$router.push(name: 'article', params: {name: 'something'})`, it works just fine. But when I then use that url, `/article/something`, the route doesn't match and the page is blank.

But if I just use `/:name` instead of `/article/:name`, everything works just fine. Does anyone have any idea why the `/article` part could be causing the route to fail to match? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Route definition:

```
{
    path: '/article/:name',
    name: 'article',
    component: () => import('../views/Article.vue'),
    props: true,
  }
```

When I navigate to `/article/something`, the page is blank, no matter what something is. But if I have the following route definition:

```
{
    path: '/:name',
    name: 'article',
    component: () => import('../views/Article.vue'),
    props: true,
  }
```

and navigate to `/something`, it works just fine.

Comment: Can you show your route definition and the link that isn't working?

Comment: If you get a blank page, surely there'd be some sort of error in your browser console. If so, what is it?

Comment: When you say _"when I use that url"_, do you men you're clicking a link like `<router-link to="/article/something">` or you're typing the URL directly into your location bar?

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'. will edit with route definition and link

Comment: When you say "navigate", what are you referring to?  You've said it works when you do a programmatic router `push`, but haven't shown any link or explained what you mean by "use that url".  Are you typing it in the browser URL bar or linking to it, etc.  If linking, can you show the link template code?  If typing, can you show the full url?

Comment: Yep, I'm typing it in the browser URL bar. full link would be localhost:8080/article/something, whereas localhost:8080/something does work

Comment: And you're using Vue-CLI devServer?  When you push programatically, does the route change successfully but then fail to work when you refresh?

Comment: Yes, and yes, that's exactly the behavior I'm getting.

Comment: Also, just realized that this problem happens with any url of the form /x/x or /x/x/x, etc. Basically anything with more than one slash, regardless of route params or what x actually is.

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong to me here (though your `$router.push` code is missing some brackets and the error you got sounds like a template tag error).  Maybe you could show all your template code or try to reproduce this project at [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/).  Create a new Sandbox and use Vue Router Template by posva.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210795/vue-cli-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token seems to be the same issue