# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' VueJS PWA

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, vue.js, progressive-web-apps

When I generate the production version of my PWA built with VueJS I got this error in Google Chrome after deploying it to my server:

- `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` in app.21fde857.js:1
- `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` in chunk-vendors.d1f8f63f.js:1

I take a look in the Network tab of the console and in both files `chunk-vendors.d1f8f63f.js` and `app.21fde857.js` the `index.html` is coming back with a status 200.

Why this occurs?

**OBS:** Locally this works perfectly.

Comment: Take a look at the response the browser is receiving for those files. Starting with `<` suggests an HTML page is coming back, possibly a 404 or the index page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution that doesn't require hand-editing your dist assets.
Simply add the following property to the exports of your vue.config.js:

`publicPath: './'`

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.

Comment: When you set publicPath and rebuild, new index.html will have appropiate path to its assets (assuming that you are having a vitual host or domain pointed to index.html)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I put `publicPath: '/'` in vue.config.js as bellow

```
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/'
}
```

Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add <%= BASE_URL %> on all links in index.html
   (Example: `<link href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon/apple-icon-144x144.png">`)
2. And add the **base** tag (Example: `<base href="https://mywebsite.com" />`) in the **head** tag, and now this works perfectly.

**Old answer**

I found a solution. I have to add a manually a `.` in every `src` in the **index.html** file in the `dist/` folder. (Example: `<link href=./js/chunk-vendors.d1f8f63f.js rel=preload as=script>`)

In the **index.html** of the source code, I have added **<%= BASE_URL %>** in every link, (Example:  `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="<%= BASE_URL %>favicon/apple-icon-144x144.png">`), as well as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210795/vue-cli-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token), but this doesn't work, I think that this error occurs because of it.

Answer (score 0):

This is because app.xxxxx.js and vendors.xxxx.js are not getting the base URL of your project.

Just add the base tag (`<base href="https://yourdomain.com" />`) to the `<head>` tag in your project's index.html file