# Unexpected token '<' when using publicPath in vue-cli 4

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I want to use prefix for my routes and assets, and based on vue-cli documentation I'm using pablicPath in `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/foo/'
}
```

but when I build the project on production I get this error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` 
what's wrong here and how should I fix it?

Comment: Does the error tell you where the unexpected token is encountered?

Comment: @3limin4t0r unfortunately no

Answer (score 2):

You can try putting this in your vue.config.js in the project root directory:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: '/foo',
  outputDir: 'dist/foo',
}
```

I refer here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4852#issuecomment-596266161

Comment: Need to build. first by outputDir: 'dist', then outputDir: 'dist/foo'

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding `<base href="/" />` into the `<head>` of your index.html. Hope it will work.

Comment: check these links https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4852 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210795/vue-cli-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token , let me know if it helped you!