# Error running npm run serve in a Vue.js Project that uses Firebase

Tags: firebase, vue.js, npm

I tried running a Vue.js project that uses Firebase but after running `npm run serve` the following error is displayed.

```
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
C:\Users\rjdla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\JoinRequestPlugin.js:1
�aO��8�§◄♦�[~����s♣�U<�E?NjE��▼v�s��&_▼��@�&���-�ߞ��‼�����G→��0�☼♀�RÄ�j�x☺k (��♀��


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rjdla\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\ResolverFactory.js:17:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51210795/vue-cli-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Comment: I already tried deleting node modules and reinstalling node but the problem still persists.

Comment: What about answers for above post ?